# Swift - SWRevealViewController menu placed after the status bar

Tags: ios, swift, statusbar, swrevealviewcontroller

I'm using SWRevealViewController menu and I have a header view for the table. You can see the table controller view structure and constrains:

[image]

And this is how my menu looks like [image]

but I need it to be like [image]

I tried :

`self.profileHeader.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: -20, width: profileHeader.frame.width, height: profileHeader.frame.height + 20)`

But nothing changed.

Comment: Try using a normal UIViewController, and adjust constraints for the tableView manually check top constraint linked to view and not to top layout guide, I hope this helps you, let me know about

Comment: @ReinierMelian It works as expected :) Thank You.

Comment: I post my comment as Answer, to avoid this question remains as unanswered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a normal `UIViewController`, and adjust constraints for the `tableView` manually **check top constraint linked to view and not to top layout guide**.

I hope this helps you, let me know about